# How to decide number of mysql partitions

Tags: database, partitioning, mysql, database-performance

I have a giant mysql table (for logging). Something like:

logger (sha1)
   timestamp
   action

so there are expected to be around 100k loggers. Each logging say 100 lines on average. This would bring the table to about 100 million rows pretty quickly.

I need to have inserts (appends really) done pretty quickly as a lot of loggers write entries at once.

Generally queries will be 'give me all the logs from logger 'x' ordered by date'.

So I was going to use mysql partitioning: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html

My question is, how to find the balance between number of partitions, and partition size ?

As the logger is a UUID and is a sha1 number, I was thinking to make mysql just make one partition for each sha1 value, so basically each logger would have their own DB table file.

Any other suggestions appreciated

Comment: So it turns out that the maximum number of partitions is 1024. Now I guess I need some algorithm that'll evenly split up sha1 values into 1024 different partitions. Or advice on why 1024 partitions would be a bad idea.

Comment: So I'm thinking to go with partition by hash: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-hash.html - but the question remains, how to decide the number of partitions.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to split something up into a specified number is to use the modulus function.

So, perhaps if you took the first 4 hex characters of the SHA1 hash, converted those to an integer (yields up to 65,025), and mod 1024, like this:

```
aa00 % 1024 = 512
```

in decimal

```
43520 % 1024 = 512
```

All the numbers that return 512 can go in the same partition. The calculation will yield values from 0 to 1023.

Comment: +1 because I didn't think of that, but not quite right for for my sha1 value as it's not just a teeny integer. I think 'partion by hash' should set me right, but how to decide the ideal number of partitions..

Comment: @matiu, since a cryptographically secure hash, such as SHA1, is evenly distributed, there's no need to convert the entire hash into an integer for the calculation. You can simply use the first few bytes as I suggested. This should yield good distribution with deterministic (non-random) results.